# Como puedo ejecutar una función enviada por parametro desde otra función

Tags: javascript, angularjs, funciones, function

Me explico, quiero hacer una caja modal en la que meconfirme una acción que quiera hacer un usuario.. hasta aqui facil, el problema viene que yo haciendolo dinamicamente, entonces lleno un objeto global (utilizando angular)

```
$scope.confirmationAction = function($titleData,$typePanel = 'info',$description,$btnFunction)
{
   $scope.ConfirmationAction.title = $titleData;
   $scope.ConfirmationAction.type = $typePanel;
   $scope.ConfirmationAction.description = $description;
   $scope.ConfirmationAction.function = $btnFunction;
};
```

hasta aqui todo va bien el problema es cuando quiero ejecutar la función que esta almacenada en el objeto... no he encontrado forma posible para hacerlo... he intentado toda la documentación que he podido encontrar

```
<button id="btnAcceptConfirmationAction" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center" ng-click="dinamicFunction(ConfirmationAction.function)">Confirmar</button>


$scope.dinamicFunction = function(functionTest)
{


$value = $scope.ConfirmationAction.function;

var resu = $value(); //No Funciono
window[$value](); //No Funciono
$value();  //No funciono


return resu;
}
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: que version de angular estas usando? en que componentes estas usando esas funciones? como estas injectando las dependencias?

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo emulando el error? Personalmente no logro entender exactamente cual es el problema.

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 1.6.6 
Si vale, ya comparto el link

Comment: var resu = $value("titulo", "info", "description", "btnFunction"); debería devoler el resultado en forma de objeto, por lo que después hacer return resu; un resu.title debería contener la cadena "titulo". Es decir, creo que tal vez es que no pasas parámetros requeridos a la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre una solución sencilla para este complicado error.

El error de por si sucedia que estaba enviando el nombre de la función entre coillas simples, era por esto que cuando queria ejecutarlo no respondia, ya que lo tomaba como una cadena de texto.

La solución es cuando se este enviando la función se debe enviar el nombre exacto de la función sin comillas.

```
ng-click="confirmationAction('Titulo','color Panel','Mensaje',funcionSinComillas)">
```

Asi de simple